# How is this kind of digital drawing named?

Tags: shapes, terminology, style-identification

I saw kind of "digital" geometrical shapes drawing on some websites.

I'm interested in creating some by myself (for wallpaper or logo purpose) and are looking for some inspiration.

Do you have any idea of what can i search in Google to find more of piece of art/digital drawing like this one?

[image: simple shapes drawing]

**How is this kind of digital drawing named**? I though it could be fractal but it's not exactly the same... Abstract? It seems to be close of Origami... It's all about drawing something using only simple shapes.

It seems Guild Wars 2 artwork use kind of similar drawing method/style: we can see all picture is built only using some blurred and "raw" superposed shapes.

[image: Guild Wars Artwork]

Comment: As per @AndrewH's comment for the first image, the second is simply a painting, whether it be digital or physical. It's pretty much a fantasy art style, or maybe modernist or realist. Without looking at the image in great detail it's pretty impossible to say. There's a possibility that the second image is a 3D rendering of a landscape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top image could be considered an [abstract low polygon design](https://www.google.com/search?q=abstract%20low%20polygon%20design&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4_qbD4-jMAhXGNz4KHUk1A_gQ_AUIBygB&biw=2560&bih=1258). I don't think the second image can be considered 1 style.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean what kind of software was used to make it? For example, raster images (made by pixels with software such as Photoshop), vector images (made by mathematical equations to create lines with software such as Illustrator), or perhaps in your examples, 3D modelling/animation?

The images you showed would likely be 3D modelling/animation where a 3D model is made and then rendered (coloured and lighted scenes). There are many free 3D modeling and rendering softwares available, one of them is Blender. Blender has many users and many free tutorials on the internet.

Comment: This type of question is about identifying what's the style of the sample(s) provided. In that sense your answer doesn't provide much info on what's being asked. If you want to know more about how the site works check the [help].

Comment: The question wording was vague, so I wanted to clarify before answering. The image looked to be like a rendered image so I specified it seems to be a rendered image of a computer generated 3D model .

Comment: Once you have enough rep you can use the comments to ask for more information.